# Excel VBA - Create table(ListObject) from existing query(Conenction Only)

Tags: excel, vba

Using VBA in Excel I am trying to use a triggered event to create a new table with ListObjects.Add() from an existing query that has been created only as a connection and added to the data model, but must be getting the syntax wrong for the source.

I have a query called "DetailedProfit"

- Created from *Data > Get Data > From Other Sources > From ODBC*
- No DSN
- Advanced options to specify connection string to IBM DB2 database using *iSeries Access ODBC Driver* and query
- Used power query editor to transform data as well as some steps created with advanced editor
- This works as intended
- Loaded to "Only Create Connection" and added to data model

I have a triggering event which I would like to load the detailed profit connection into a newly created table, same as if I had selected Load to "Table" which runs this code

```
Set myTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=xlSrcModel, Source:=ThisWorkbook.Connections("ThisWorkbookDataModel"), Destination:=Range("$A$1")).TableObject
```

I have tried chaning the source from a WorkbookConnection to WorkbookQuery as below as well

```
Set myTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=xlSrcModel, Source:=ThisWorkbook.Queries("DetailedProfit"), Destination:=Range("$A$1")).TableObject
```

Both run into "Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument"

I believe I have the source wrong, so I have tried adding watches for both sources and crawling through properties, but I do not see anything that appears to be the data model connection to my query in the workbook connections.

Do I just have the syntax of how to refer to that connection wrong, or am I going about this completely wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried recording a macro see if that helps with syntax?  Changing the Load To when I record gives:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=DetailedProfit;Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
```

If you want to load data to VBA to do more work with it you can put Data Model data into a record set following this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/72122340/5830541.  From there you could use Range.CopyFromRecordset.

From the linked answer I did have to change the query string to DAX syntax.
That is, instead of SELECT:

```
    rs.Open "SELECT * From $" & TABLE_NAME & ".$" & TABLE_NAME, conn
```

I used `"EVALUATE '" & TABLE_NAME & "'"` for rs.Open [Source].

Comment: Thank you, the advice to record a macro and look at the code was invaluable. I got something different than you, here is what I got, which works for me.  

    `ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=xlSrcModel, Source:=ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - DetailedProfit"), Destination:=Range("$A$1")).TableObject`
<br/><br/>
So if you are looking to load an existing query that has been loaded to the data model the syntax appears to be `Source:=ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - _QUERY_NAME_")`

You will then need to call the TableObject's **.Refresh** method to load populate the table.