# Access data from Power Pivot Data Model in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powerpivot, adodb

I am using under Excel 2016 the [Student Data Model sample workbook with completed Data Model](http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/1/0/210B5CF1-7E21-4119-9481-B2C44A6F48B5/Student%20Data%20Model%20-%20Complete.xlsx) provided by Microsoft and I have a simple question: **how can I access Data Model data from VBA** with a RecordSet?

I tried the following without success:

```
Public Sub Test()
  Dim conn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, sql As String
  Set conn = ThisWorkbook.Connections("ThisWorkbookDataModel").ModelConnection.ADOConnection
  sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Students"
  Set rs = conn.Execute(sql)
End Sub
```

I get the following error:

[image]

Thanks for your help,

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51089991/can-i-get-data-from-power-query-to-a-vba-variable/72122340#72122340) answer

Comment: Your syntax of the SQL statement should be `Evaluate tbl_Students`, i.e. `sql = Evaluate tbl_Students`.

Comment: Thank you, it works indeed. Should I understand that we can use only DAX queries (that I am absolutely not familiar with), and not SQL queries in that context?

Comment: You can also use a syntax like `SELECT * FROM $tblName.$tblName`.  Just follow the link mentioned by @SpectralInstance

Comment: Thanks, `SELECT * FROM $tblName.$tblName` works indeed!
However, are join supported? The following throws an error:

`SELECT $tbl_Students.$tbl_Students.[Student ID] FROM $tbl_Students.$tbl_Students INNER JOIN $tbl_Grades.$tbl_Grades ON ($tbl_Students.$tbl_Students.[Student ID] = $tbl_Grades.$tbl_Grades.[Student ID])`